# What is the meaning of "a flicker of amusement" in the sentence?

Tags: absolute-construction

What is the meaning of "a flicker of amusement" in the following sentence?

> He looked at me, **a flicker of amusement** in his cold eyes.

"Source : Collins COBUILD Advanced Learner's Dictionary "

Does "He looked at me, a flicker of amusement in his cold eyes" mean "He looked at me, and he was a flicker of amusement in his cold eyes" ? or does "He looked at me, and he had a flicker of amusement in his cold eyes" ?

When a subject and verb are omitted in a sentence, how do we know which subject and verb are omitted? Should we assume that the verb "have" is omitted when it does not seem that the verb "be" is omitted?  Or is the "preposition" omitted in sentences?

Comment: The cited sentence *does* have a subject *(he)* and verb *(looked)*. The words *a flicker of amusement in his cold eyes* are an ***adverbial phrase of manner*** - that *could* optionally be introduced using the preposition ***with***.

Comment: Is it grammatically correct to use a noun( a flicker of amusement) as an adverbial phrase of manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a "nominative absolute" construction (which goes by several other names, as well). This construction usually includes a nominal phrase modified by another phrase (which I consider "adjectival", but others might use a different term), and this one is fairly typical:

- a flicker of amusement <-- nominal phrase
- in his cold eyes <-- modifier

Your second interpretation is correct, but I think that the sentence's meaning could be slightly better expressed as:

> He looked at me, and there was a flicker of amusement in his cold eyes.

You can read more about this construction [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_absolute).

Comment: I'd say it's the verbless analogue of the rather unnatural-sounding  "He looked at me, a flicker of amusement being in his cold eyes".

Comment: I think that eyes that flicker, glimmer, shine, blaze, etc, are annoying clichés, along with mouths that curl (scornfully, usually), eyebrows that shoot up, etc.